# можно ли встроить блок с вк и чтобы на странице он отображался с твоими стилями ?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, style

как это сделать? поделитесь какими нибудь ссылками

Comment: Конечно, опиши стили в теге атрибутом `style=" color : red !important; "`

Comment: Я понимаю, просто как это сделать, где прописать эту строчку? ( шутка)

Comment: `<div style=" color : red !important; "> Lyuba Ivanova  </div>`
Правда учти, что `JS` Перерисует
`document.querySelector('div').style.color = "green";`

Comment: Слушаю : ввв ленинград точка ру . Ну  я попробую со стилями, просто не пробывал еще, а юзал userstyles

Comment: Рад, что у тя хорошее настроение...

Comment: Почитай  http://htmlbook.ru/css/%21important